# What type of phrase is "Of Unsaid Goodbyes"? Is it grammatically valid for a title of a book?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, etymology, prepositions

Specifically, in what way has "of" been used here?
Is this a common use of the word?

Comment: _[On the subject] of..._ It's not common, but there are precedents. _Of Mice and Men_ is probably the most famous (it's a partial quotation from Burns, but works as a book title). I found [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337077/what-is-role-of-the-word-of-at-the-beginning-of-a-title) while searching.

Comment: Certainly no one would every title a book "Of Human Bondage", and, if they did, no one would ever read it!

Comment: I must say it is an intriguing title:  the book that has it had better be wonderful!.  I suspect the ‘of’ in titles owes something to the Latin ‘de’ (strictly ‘about’) and French ‘de’) (either ‘about’ or ‘of’ .

Comment: Donald Frame's excellent 1957 translation of _The Complete Essays of Montaigne_ contains 107 essays and essay titles, of which 71 begin with the word "Of."

Comment: It is fine grammatically, but note that titles don't need to follow grammar rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/of)*** is a preposition meaning: *relating to.*

> *And what of (= tell me about) young Adrian? How is he?* (formal)

(Cambridge Dictionary)

The above usage as well as the one you cite is more literary.

Answer (score 1):

*Of* is a preposition, that can function as the start of a title, as can *on* (as in 'On the Subject of...') or *about* (as in 'About a Boy'). It even stands to reason, that it is in some form an abbreviation of 'On the Subject Of...', though this is speculative. To me as a non-native english speaker it sounds very correct, since in german, the word *von* is used similarly and mirrors the function of *of*. Originally titles starting with *Of* suggested a scientific or at least non-fictional content, but in fact, have since been used more often in fictional contexts. I am still waiting for a title riddiculing this entirely, and using it ironically as in 'Of Farts'.

Titles I quickly found scrolling through ISBN (https://isbndb.com/search/books/Of), starting with 'Of ...':

- *Of Courage, of Grief, of Celebration: Making the Most of Your Life in Changing Times*
- *Of Vicissitudes Of Things*
- *Of Regimen Of Health*
- *Of The Serpent, Of Paradise, And Of The Garden Of Eden*
- *Of Poverty Of Spirit Of Observed In The Midst Of Riches*
- *Of the plurality of worlds*
- *Of The Origin Of The World Of Fire*
- *Of Old:Poems of Time: Poems of Time*
- *Of Men & Of Angels*

On a side note: Apparently, there exist several books simply titled 'Of'.

On another side note: There is a band called 'Of Monsters and Men'.